# Retrying Selenium Geckodriver action after connection reset error?

Tags: python, selenium, geckodriver

Sometimes I get a connection reset while automating using Selenium with geckodriver, and I'm wondering how I can cleanly retry without having to start my whole script over? The problem is that it happens during any action, including navigating to a URL, but also clicking a URL or javascript loading a resource.

Comment: Address the reason of _connection reset_, possibly you can't recover even through `try-catch {}`

Comment: It's caused by any browsing - most obviously, using webdriver's get, ex: `driver.get(some url)`. But any action that loads new pages as well, such a running `.click()` on a link. Firefox's exact error says 'Secure Connection Failed - The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.'..


I don't think I can try-catch anything other than a normal `driver.get()`, since in the case of clicking a link, I won't be able to re-click a link if the page has gone to an error page.